# Way to auto-approve for pending acceptance state after TG attachment is added?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is there an auto-approve for pending acceptance state after TG attachment is added except for using resource aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment_accepter ?

I have a variable, which I obtain from aws api for regions with TGW IDs except the current region

For e.g i am in us-east-2 my variable is,

TGW_PEERS = [{"id": "tgw-xxx", "region": "eu-west-1",  "name": "TGW0001_EUW1"}, {"id": "tgw-xxx", "region": "us-west-2", "cidr": "", "name": "TGW0001_USW2"}]

I have a resource aws_ec2_transit_gateway_peering_attachment

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_peering_attachment" "TGW-PEERS" {
  count = length(var.TGW_PEERS) 
  peer_region             = var.TGW_PEERS[count.index].region 
  peer_transit_gateway_id = var.TGW_PEERS[count.index].id 
  transit_gateway_id      = data.aws_ec2_transit_gateway.TGW.id
  tags = {
    Name = format("PEER_%s", var.TGW_PEERS[count.index].name)
    Side = "Initiator"    
  }
}
```

**But when I apply the above, TGW attachments go in pending acceptance state and enabling "Auto-accept shared attachments" does not help either**

A way to fix it is i will have to do this for every region and create aliases, resource statements for all the other regions except itself.
Which I dont want to do :)

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "us-west-2"
  region     = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment_accepter" "TGW-ACCEPTOR" {
  provider = aws.us-west-2 
  transit_gateway_attachment_id = data.aws_ec2_transit_gateway.TGW.id
  tags = {
    Name = "Yo"
    Side = "Accepter"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Auto-accept shared attachments" applies for [TG VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/tgw-vpc-attachments.html) attachments . However you are trying to do [TG peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/tgw-peering.html) attachment. For such attachments, there is **no auto-accept**:

> To activate the **peering** attachment, the owner of the accepter transit gateway **must accept** the peering attachment request. This is required even if both transit gateways are in the **same account**. The peering attachment must be in the pendingAcceptance state. Accept the peering attachment request from the Region that the accepter transit gateway is located in.

The `aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment_accepter` you are trying to use applies to TG VPC attachments, not TG peering ones.

Comment: That makes sense thank you. It is a bummer. and yes Ill use another resource. I was using the wrong one. But it is not fun to use several regions and resource statements :(

Comment: Is there a way to loop through provider within resource ? 
Something like 
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-west-2"
  region = "us-west-2"
}
provider = format("aws.%s", var.TGW_PEERS[count.index].region)

I can have aws providers predefined

Comment: @VinitaShah No sure. You could make new question explain what you wish to achieve with these providers.